# Capture httpresponse object from webBrowser control

Tags: webbrowser-control, httpresponse

I need to capture the response content after the request is sent from webBrowser control.

When I have httpAnalyzer running, I am able to capture some important data (raw data) in `response content` that is passed back to webBrowser control.

Any ideas?

More info:
I have an internal site which uses flash to generate reports. I was able to automate page loading and simulate button clicking that produce the report. When I use the httpAnalyzer, I am able to see raw data that I need to capture; but I don't know how to actually get to response object.

Comment: take a look at FiddlerCore http://fiddler2.com/fiddlercore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used FiddlerCore: http://fiddler2.com/fiddlercore

```
    private void button_click()
    {
        Thread myThread = new Thread(delegate()
        {
            fiddlerRun();
        });
        myThread.Start();
    }

    private void fiddlerRun()
    {
        #region AttachEventListeners
        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.BeforeResponse += delegate(Fiddler.Session oS)
        {
            String s1 = oS.GetResponseBodyAsString(); // this is where response is catched
            //I know that response must contain specific word - if it is there- catch it!
            if (s1.Contains("License") )
            {
               //do my stuff with response
               //...
               //stop Fiddler
               Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Shutdown();
               System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(750);
            }
        };
        #endregion AttachEventListeners
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Starting FiddlerCore...");
        Fiddler.CONFIG.IgnoreServerCertErrors = false;
        try
        {
            Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Startup(8877, true, true);
        }
        catch { }
    }
```